# Object with non-trivial destructor shouldn't be used in global space

Tags: c++, c++17

I have read on a Google C++ Style Guide that:

> When destructors are trivial, their execution is not subject to
> ordering at all (they are effectively not "run"); otherwise we are
> exposed to the risk of accessing objects after the end of their
> lifetime. Therefore, we only allow objects with static storage
> duration if they are trivially destructible. Fundamental types (like
> pointers and int) are trivially destructible, as are arrays of
> trivially destructible types. Note that variables marked with
> constexpr are trivially destructible.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables

As an example of a bad usage is presented the code below:

```cpp
const std::string kFoo = "foo";
```

According to:

> otherwise we are exposed to the risk of accessing objects after the end of their lifetime.

my question is: in which situation this code might be dangerous?

Comment: This is strongly related to [the static initialization fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).  Only that it's the _uninitialization_ flipside.

Comment: If you have multiple static objects that depend on each other's exitance you can run into UB on the initialization and destruction

Comment: Google styleguide is notoriously bad. This is an example of absolute nonsense. There is absolutely nothing wrong with static objects with non-trivial destructors in general, in particular, with provided example of `std::string`. There are **some** cases when it could be problematic, but no general rule exists.

Comment: `const std::string kFoo = "foo";` is not dangerous.  `some_type_that_holds_pointer_to_string foo(&kFoo);` in a different TU can be, as we don't know what's destroyed first.  If `foo` Uses `kFoo` after it's destoyed, well now you're in UB land.

Comment: Their guide is being overly cautious and banning a lot of valid uses so that bad uses can't be used.

Comment: @SergeyA, That is the result of years of experience, and what is explained about dependencies between global `static` variables is not nonsense (but the question sample is). Do you know any better code-style guide line?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani i have about twice as much experience as average Google employee, including ones contributing to the style guide, so I would appreciate if you refrain from using seniority as a justification. Like I said, some usage of globals is problematic, some is not. Yes, I do know a lot of better style guides (i created some of them for my companies). No, they are not public. As for a good public guide without cargo-cult, I like the one from isocpp: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @SergeyA, Thanks for the explanation. I'm a junior and don't have that much experience, and I really appreciate it if you make public style guides.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani dependencies between global static variables are an issue regardless of trivial destruction.

Comment: *"in which situation this code might be dangerous?"* -- by "this code" are you referring specifically to the one example in your question, or are you referring more generally to any code that demonstrates "bad usage"? If the former, I advise paying closer to the words "exposed" and "risk". The guidelines do not say that every example of "bad usage" will be dangerous, but that it *might* be. Riding a bicycle the wrong way in the middle of a street up a hill (where oncoming traffic cannot see you) is risky. Never riding a bicycle eliminates this risk. There are also less stringent approaches.